# Compute the infinite sum of product of sin and exponential function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I wonder can we find the special function related with limit of the following sum, let
$$f(t,a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(na)\sin(nb)e^{-\frac{1}{2}n^2t}$$
it is said that: there exist functions $g, h$ and the number $\lambda>0$ such that for all $a, b,$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(t,a,b)}{g(a)h(b)e^{-\lambda t}}=1$$

I want to find the function $g,h$ and $\lambda$ so that the above limit hold. I want to proceed in following way: find the upper and lower bound for $f(t,a,b)$, and then find $g,h$ and $\lambda$. But I don't know how to start. I also try WolframAlpha on specific value of $a,b,t$, it seems that the value related with $ab,a+b$.

Can anyone help on this limit?

Answer (score 2):

I have find the solution from Gregory F. Lawler book:"Random Walk and the Heat Equation" page 77.

$$
p(t, y, x, U)=\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k^{2} t / 2} \sin (k x) \sin (k y)
$$
Note that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} e^{-k^{2} t / 2} \sin (k x) \sin (k y)\right| \leq \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} e^{-k t}=\frac{e^{-2 t}}{1-e^{-t}}
$$
Hence, as $t \rightarrow \infty,$ the sum on the right-hand side is dominated by the $k=1$ term,
$$
p(t, y, x, U) \sim \frac{2}{\pi} e^{-t / 2} \sin (x) \sin (y), \quad t \rightarrow \infty
$$